# Azure Workload Identity Federation and Managed Identity: login.microsoftonline.com returns 401

Tags: azure, openid-connect, azure-managed-identity, workload-identity

Given following setup:

- User assigned identity with federated identity credentials, pointing to AKS's service account, in place
- An AKS cluster with service account, with OIDC issuer and workload identity enabled, 1.23.8
- A pod is running, which gets populated with the ENVs

  - AZURE_AUTHORITY_HOST: https://login.microsoftonline.com/
  - AZURE_CLIENT_ID: <my-client-id>
  - AZURE_FEDERATED_TOKEN_FILE: /var/run/secrets/azure/tokens/azure-identity-token
  - AZURE_TENANT_ID: <my-tenant-id>

Using Maven azure-identity for the `ManagedIdentity` instance:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
  <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.0-beta.3</version>
  <!--      <version>1.7.3</version> tried different versions ... -->
</dependency>
```

Java snippet:

```
ManagedIdentityCredential managedIdentityCredential =
  new ManagedIdentityCredentialBuilder()
  .build();
QueueClient queue = new QueueClientBuilder()
  .credential(managedIdentityCredential)
  .endpoint("https://<my-storage-account>.queue.core.windows.net")
  .queueName("test")
  .buildClient();
```

This results in:

> java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL:
> [https://login.microsoftonline.com/\](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%5C)<my-tenant-id>/oauth2/v2.0/token
> ...
> [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] ERROR com.azure.identity.ManagedIdentityCredential - Azure Identity => ERROR in getToken() call for scopes [https://storage.azure.com/.default]: Managed Identity authentication is not available.
> [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] ERROR  com.azure.core.implementation.AccessTokenCache - Failed to acquire a new access token.

Any suggestions what might be missing in the picture? Thx!

Comment: Were you able to figure out this issue?

Comment: @Gorgon_Union See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be many reasons leading to this 401 error. But in my particular case: I had a wrong Kubernetes namespace configuration in the Federated Credential ... maybe this helps somebody else, too.